# Qt setting an app icon for a windows app .rc file not found

Tags: c++, qt, rc, qt5.3

I followed everything described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/appicon.html) to set an app icon.

Created .rc file / placed it in the same directory where .pro file is.

Added the following line to the .rc file

> IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "myappico.ico"

Added the following line to the .pro file

```
RC_FILE = myapp.rc
```

Run QMake and run the app and the following error message comes up

```
:-1: error: error: ..\ZombieAttack\myapp.rc: No such file or directory
:-1: warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Press Rebuild All. Is it work or you get error No rule to make target ... needed by... ?

Comment: Did that but didn't make any difference :(

Answer (score 1):

Assigning an icon to the application is automated by qmake in Qt5. Just add the following to the project file:

```
win32:RC_ICONS += myappico.ico
```

Comment: That's interesting.. I have added the line above and it now says `:-1: error: error: ..\ZombieAttack\ZombieAttack_resource.rc: No such file or directory` .. However, I have checked the build directory and ZombieAttack_resource.rc file is in it.. :(

Comment: Remove the .rc file and the related line in .pro. Delete build files and rebuild your project.

Comment: Still same thing :( Something I am doing must be wrong but what is it?